# style-specific colors in grouped bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bar chart with several groups/series. Each group has its own color. It is simple to specify exact color for each of the groups but is there any "standard" way to find colors (color map, palette, cycle, whatever...) which are suitable for chart style (http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html)? For example the `"dark_background"` style would match better with different colors than some light styles. If I do not specify the color for each of the groups, then the bar color is based on the style but then all groups are the same, which I do not want.

UPDATE: to see how it behaves try adjust the example http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html
by removing explicit bar colors and setting a style.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('dark_background')  # SETTING STYLE!!!

N = 5
men_means = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
men_std = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, men_means, width, yerr=men_std)  # NO BAR COLOR!!!

women_means = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
women_std = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, women_means, width, yerr=women_std)  # NO BAR COLOR !!!

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))


def autolabel(rects):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Consecutive bar plots should have consecutive colors. Can you give a [MCVE]?

Comment: I updated the question to contain code... as you can see the groups "men" and "women" have the same color.